# DOMException: Failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 0 is not a valid index. - Dropdown - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown

I have a custom dropdown in React:

```
             <div>
                 <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">              
                     <span className="caret"></span>
                 </button>
                 <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                     {
                         OPTIONS.map((item, ind)=>{
                             return(
                                 <li key={ind}>
                                     <option value={item.value}>
{item.value}</option>
                                 </li>
                             );
                        })
                    }
               </ul>
            </div>
```

and I got the following mistake:  Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 0 is not a valid index.

Is it possible to solve this issue using the structure shown above for the dropdown .

Comment: Are you sure that this is the part of the code that is causing the error? Doesn't the error message include the filename and line number that caused the error?

Comment: The problem occurs on all pages where the drop-down menu is placed, if I delete the drop-down menu the problem no longer appears. The problem also occurs again when I click on the drop-down button or when I try to select an option.

Comment: First of all, you are using an <option> element inside a <li> where you need to place it inside a <select> parent element. I think you should consider restructuring your markup. @cabita (Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

Comment: Also, we are missing a lot of code here in order to understand what's happening. Which code is responsible for the custom dropdown?